# org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a problem with Spring Boot Rabbit Mq. I have 2 listeners which listen the same queue but handle different objects:

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{changeDataQueue.name}")
public class CreateDayAheadTradeListener implements DayAheadTradeEventListener<CreateDayAheadTradeRequest> {

@Autowired
private DayAheadTradeRepository repository;

@Override
@RabbitHandler
public void process(final CreateDayAheadTradeRequest event) {
    // Do something
}

}
```

And the next one:

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{changeDataQueue.name}")
public class UpdateDayAheadTradeListener implements DayAheadTradeEventListener<ModifyDayAheadTradeStatusRequest> {

@Autowired
private DayAheadTradeRepository repository;

@Override
@RabbitHandler
public void process(final ModifyDayAheadTradeStatusRequest event) {
   // Do something 
}

}
```

The Rabbit Config is:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {

private final String createDayAheadTradesRouting = CreateDayAheadTradeRequest.class
        .getAnnotation(Routing.class)
        .routingKey();

private final String updateDayAheadTradesRouting = ModifyDayAheadTradeStatusRequest.class
        .getAnnotation(Routing.class)
        .routingKey();

private final String requestDayAheadTradesRouting = DayAheadTradeRequest.class
        .getAnnotation(Routing.class)
        .routingKey();

@Bean
public TopicExchange topicExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("schedule"); // exchange name
}

@Bean
public Queue changeDataQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder
            .durable("dayahead.trades.data") // queue template name
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Queue requestQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder
            .nonDurable("dayahead.trades.request") // queue template name
            .exclusive()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Binding createDataBinding(final Queue changeDataQueue, final TopicExchange topicExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(changeDataQueue)
            .to(topicExchange)
            .with(createDayAheadTradesRouting);
}

@Bean
public Binding updateDataBinding(final Queue changeDataQueue, final TopicExchange topicExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(changeDataQueue)
            .to(topicExchange)
            .with(updateDayAheadTradesRouting);
}

@Bean
public Binding requestBinding(final Queue requestQueue, final TopicExchange topicExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(requestQueue)
            .to(topicExchange)
            .with(requestDayAheadTradesRouting);
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = EventUtils.createMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new MarketdataModule());
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
}

}
```

The problem is that if I create 2 separate queues for different types of objects - everything works fine, but the idea is to use one queue for several types of objects. But I have the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'no match' threw exception
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:219)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:143)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:132)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1569)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1488)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1476)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1467)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1411)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:958)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:908)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1279)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1185)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:211)
... 13 more
```

I can't find any information about it, I hope someone knows about it. Thanks

Comment: You need to show your listener container factory configuration. With two consumers on the same queue, they will compete for messages; there is no mechanism in RabbitMQ to direct messages with different types to specific consumers. Typically you would use a different queue for each type. The `@KafkaHandler` mechanism can handle multiple types as long as you have a default handler for unmatched types. But, again, each listener would need its own queue.

Comment: Gary Russell - Thank you for response. But what the better way to this situation? Creating a queue for each object, or add a listener container factory configuration?

Comment: You need a queue for each type or use a single `@RabbitListener` with two `@KafkaHandler`s, one for each type.

Comment: Make sure that both `CreateDayAheadTradeRequest ` and `ModifyDayAheadTradeStatusRequest ` implement `Serializable`. You can find more information here: https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/AMQP-573/AMQP-573.html